# ¿Cómo validar caracteres especiales de password en Java?

Tags: java, string

Estoy realizando un ejercicio donde debo pedir se ingrese un `password`, el programa deberá validar que cumpla con ciertos requerimientos de seguridad como mínimo 8 caracteres, incluir mayúsculas y números. Me falta poder incluir caracteres especiales pero no ubico como lograr ese punto. Algún consejo?

```
public class Password {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     String inputPassword;  // crea variable password

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); // Creamos Scanner

        System.out.print("Ingresa un password: ");      // Imprime solicitud de password en pantalla
        inputPassword = input.next();           // input del password

        System.out.println(PassCheck(inputPassword));   // Metodo PassCheck para validar password
        System.out.println("");

        main(args);             // bucle del programa para realizar varias pruebas

    }

    public static String PassCheck (String Password) {

        String resultado = "Intermedia: cuenta con 8 caracteres, integra además de \n" +
"letras, al menos 1 numero";    // Resultado de password valido
        int length = 0;                     // Almacenamos numero de caracteres en el pass
        int numCount = 0;                   // Variable usada para almacenar numeros en el password
        int capCount = 0;                   // Variable usada para almacenar mayusculas en el password

        for (int x =0; x < Password.length(); x++) {
            if ((Password.charAt(x) >= 47 && Password.charAt(x) <= 58) || (Password.charAt(x) >= 64 && Password.charAt(x) <= 91) ||
                (Password.charAt(x) >= 97 && Password.charAt(x) <= 122)) {

                } 

            if ((Password.charAt(x) > 47 && Password.charAt(x) < 58)) { // Cuenta la cantidad de numero
                numCount ++;
            }

            if ((Password.charAt(x) > 64 && Password.charAt(x) < 91)) { // Cuenta la cantidad de mayuscula
                capCount ++;
            }

            length = (x + 1); // Cuenta la longitud del password

        } // Final del bucle

        if (numCount < 1){              // Revisa que el password contenga minimo 1 numero
            resultado = "No tiene suficientes números el Password!";
        }

        if (capCount < 1) {                            // Revisa que el password contenga minimo 1 mayuscula
            resultado = "No tiene suficientes mayusculas el Password!";
        }

        if (length < 8){                // Revisa la longitud minima de 8 caracteres del password
            resultado = "Inutilizable: no cumple con el mínimo de caracteres!";
        }

            return (resultado);         // Retorna el valor de "resultado"

    } //Finaliza chequeo del método Passcheck
} // Fin de clase validatepassword
```

Comment: Como consejo se me ocurre que crees un array constante con todos los caracteres especiales y compruebes si cada caracter de tu password está incluido en ese array. Si lo está, tu password tiene caracteres especiales. Sería más sencillo que ir comparando con los valores ascii de cada caracter especial.

Comment: Otra forma es crear una [expresión regular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresión_regular) y verificar que la cadena coincida. De esa forma te ahorras una gran cantidad de código. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar con este formato de regexp:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\S+$).{8,}$
```

[Regex password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation)

Comment: pero aqui como aplicaria el regexp (si habia visto ese post) ya que debo designar un password y aqui quiero que valide contra el que ingrese el usuario? :(

Comment: @Dorayaki, ¿podrías describir qué hace esa expresión regular?

Answer (score 1):

Estoy haciendo algo muy parecido y tu código me ayudo muchísimo, aca te lo dejo  con los caracteres y el arroba (@) que es muy necesario.

```
String resultado = "Muy Buena";    // Resultado de password valido

int length = 0;                     // Almacenamos numero de caracteres en el pass
int numCount = 0;                   // Variable usada para almacenar numeros en el password
int capCount = 0;                   // Variable usada para almacenar mayusculas en el password
int capSignos = 0;                  // Variable usada para almacenar los signos
int Arroba = 0;                     // solo la arroba -.-!

for (int x = 0; x < Password.length(); x++) {
    if ((Password.charAt(x) >= 47 && Password.charAt(x) <= 58) //numeros
            || (Password.charAt(x) >= 64 && Password.charAt(x) <= 91) //mayusculas
            || (Password.charAt(x) >= 63 && Password.charAt(x) <= 65) //Arroba
            || (Password.charAt(x) >= 32 && Password.charAt(x) <= 44) //signos
            || (Password.charAt(x) >= 97 && Password.charAt(x) <= 122)) {  //minusculas

    }
    if ((Password.charAt(x) > 63 && Password.charAt(x) < 65)) { // Cuenta laS arrobas
        Arroba++;
    }
    if ((Password.charAt(x) > 32 && Password.charAt(x) < 44)) { // Cuenta la cantidad signos
        capSignos++;
    }
    if ((Password.charAt(x) > 47 && Password.charAt(x) < 58)) { // Cuenta la cantidad de numero
        numCount++;
    }

    if ((Password.charAt(x) > 64 && Password.charAt(x) < 91)) { // Cuenta la cantidad de mayuscula
        capCount++;
    }

    length = (x + 1); // Cuenta la longitud del password

} // Final del bucle

if (capSignos < 1) {                // Revisa la longitud minima de 8 caracteres del password
    resultado = "no tiene caracteres especiales como ( ! # $ % & ' ( ) + - )";
}
if (Arroba < 1) {                // Revisa la longitud minima de 8 caracteres del password
    resultado = "Coloque un @ para mayor seguridad";
}        
if (numCount < 1) {              // Revisa que el password contenga minimo 1 numero
    resultado = "Medio";
}

if (capCount < 1) {                            // Revisa que el password contenga minimo 1 mayuscula
    resultado = "Facil";
}

if (length < 5) {                // Revisa la longitud minima de 8 caracteres del password
    resultado = "Inutilizable: no cumple con el mínimo de caracteres!";
}

jLabel2.setText(resultado);
```