# Me gustaria agregar una variable que detecte si estoy insertando un valor tipo asi @,%,$.Lo marque como valor insertado no valido

Tags: java, condiciones

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import jdk.vm.ci.meta.ValueKind;
 
public class letraynumero{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        char valor =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Inserte un valor:").charAt(0);

        if(Character.isDigit(valor)){//Si detecta que insertaste un digito ,es true
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"USTED HA INGRESADO UN NUMERO” :"+valor);
        }else if(Character.isUpperCase(valor)){//Es un true false,Si la letra esta masyuscula devuelve un true

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"USTED HA INGRESADO UNA LETRA MAYUSCULA : "+valor);
        } else { 

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"USTED HA INGRESADO UNA LETRA MINUSCULA : "+ valor);
        }
    
         
    }//main

}//class
```

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: ¿Cual opción? ¿Dónde? ¿Cual error? No somos adivinos.

Comment: Por ejemplo que inserte una @,%,etc.Lo envie como si fuera error

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo validar caracteres especiales en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309558/c%c3%b3mo-validar-caracteres-especiales-en-java)