# ¿Como puedo validar que una contraseña inicie con mayúscula? en JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, validación, contraseña

Comenzar con 1 letra mayúscula, deben tener por lo menos 1 dígito y un carácter especial y una longitud mínima de 8 caracteres.

Tengo esta expresión regular:

```
"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])()(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).{8,}$"
```

Comment: Y qué falla con esta expresión regular?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo validar caracteres especiales en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309558/c%c3%b3mo-validar-caracteres-especiales-en-java)

Comment: Debe empezar con una letra mayúscula

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar el Regex de validación de OWASP.

```
"^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,8}$"
```

Con esto se estaría filtrando sí un dígito debe aparecer al menos una vez, sí tiene una letra minúscula, mayúscula y si es de 4 - 8 caracteres.

Comment: Si, pero me piden que la primera letra deba ser mayúscula ¿como puedo hacer eso?